# how can I specify the default domain for mutt to append to unqualified addresses

Tags: linux, email, mutt

I would like to be able to type just the username of a recipient for people within my domain, and have mutt automatically qualify it for me.  That is, if I type `user1` I would like it to be transformed to `user1@example.net`.

I know with `use_domain` I can have the value of `hostname` automatically added in such cases, and I can almost get where I want if I specify `hidden_host` as well.  The problem is that my FQDN is in a sub domain, and `hidden_host` doesn't strip enough off.  For example, if my `muttrc` includes the following:

```
set hostname='host.sub.example.net'
set use_domain=yes
set hidden_host=yes
```

then if I type `user1` as a recipient it will expand to `user1@sub.example.net` instead of `user1@example.net` as I desire.

I could create an alias for each user I suppose, but that feels cumbersome and hard to keep in sync as users and mailboxes are added or changed.

Is there a way to tell `mutt` what domain I would like to have added to the unqualified names I type, or should I just "lie" about my `hostname`?

Answer (score 1):

As of Mutt version 2.2.8 in 2022, the feature you want does not exist, but it's quite easy to add if you don't mind compiling Mutt from source.  You need to edit `sendlib.c` and change `mutt_fqdn` on the `may_hide_host` branch: your simplest "hack" would be to add `return "example.net";` right there (if this binary won't be used with any other provider).

Of course, if you're compiling Mutt from source, then you need to (a) make sure all libraries are available for the features you want (otherwise you might get a Mutt that lacks these features) and (b) manually keep up-to-date with any security patches etc you want (as your distribution's package manager will no longer do this for you).  It's "not for everyone" but having said that, Mutt is not too difficult a thing to compile.

Alternatively, in `.muttrc` you can set `editor` to any program you like, including a script that runs your preferred editor and then makes its own automated changes to the resulting text file, but I wouldn't recommend this.  You'd need to find unqualified emails on appropriate lines of the header but not the body; it might be easier if you know your unqualified addresses always match a certain pattern, but make one mistake and your emails could be seriously ruined.  Plus, this approach won't catch addresses typed into Mutt's own prompts; it can catch only addresses typed into your editor.  I'm mentioning the "editor override" approach here only for completeness: in most cases it will be easier to customise the source code of Mutt itself as above.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  I'm trying to steer clear of compiling my own versions of things for non-technical reasons, but good point that would be a way to go.  I'm kind of intrigued by the editor approach, even with the well advised warnings you offer.  If I revisit this I might play with that a bit.